# Crop video part using popcorn.js

Tags: html, popcornjs

I've read the **popcorn.js** [docs](http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/index.html), but i can't seem to found a way for removing some parts of the video.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this library gives you any function to crop the video. Although, if you want a solution with popcorn.js, notice that [it offers a "sequence" feature](http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/modules/#sequence) which you could use to skip some parts of the video and simulate what you're looking for.

Comment: I assume that popcorn have this function due to popcorn maker capability to do so. Do you know another library that does let you do those kind of things?